# Column layout logic bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Take the following [example bootstrap layout](http://www.bootply.com/IKd9bk24kp).

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 a">col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 a">col 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 a">
  col 5
</div>


<div class="col-xs-7">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 b">col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 b">col 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 b">
  col 5
</div>
```

The first row here is exactly what I need, and Ideally must not change. (*If I can achieve a similar result with a more efficient layout I'm all ears.*)

The second row however I want to only have 2 sections. The col 4 on the far left needs to essentially be empty space. Everything to the right of that needs to be a single column - so col 9 and col 5 on the second row need to be merged. I'm not sure how to achieve this...

The reason I need this is so that the right hand side lines up with the start of col 9 on the first row. Like this manually edited example pic;[image] The red section is what I want to be a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it can be simplified to this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 a">col 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 a">col 5</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 a">col 5</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 b">col 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-10 b">col 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Originally I did have that layout, which *almost* worked. Unfortunately the col-2 in the first row was too big for the element I needed there, and col-1 in it's place was too small. Using the col-3 inside a col-7 was the perfect size.

Comment: i think you can customize bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system to 24 grids as an example so you will have more control over size of cols

Comment: I have considered that. Ideally I could find a solution that keeps 12 cols, but I may have to end up going with 24 and see how that works for me.

Comment: i think that is the beauty of bootstrap, that if it does not work for you out-of-the box, you can go and customize it.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've gone with 24 columns. Luckily this is a new build so there's not too much to change to convert it to the new column sizes!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want, replace the 2nd col-xs-7 with this:

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 b">col 3</div>
       <div class="col-md-9 b">col 9</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm left with an empty 5 columns to the right then. If I could somehow extend that col 9 on the end to the full width of the page and not break everything else, then that would be fine.

Comment: In the screenshot you don't have the col 5 at the end? Just leave it out?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to illustrate the end result of the two columns I'd be left with. The red area is the size of the column I need. It needs to be 100% of the row width minus the first column.

Comment: Did you try using offset? <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 a">col 9</div>
</div>